# How do I use re.UNICODE in python 2.7?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, unicode

I am trying to use the re.UNICODE flag to match a string potentially containing unicode characters, but it doesn't seem to be working.  E.g.:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(ur"(\w+)", re.UNICODE)
>>> r.findall(u"test test test", re.UNICODE)
[]
```

It works if I do not specify the unicode flag, but then obviously it will not work with unicode strings.  What do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, please give the entire error message by editing your post.

Comment: No error, it just returns an empty list.  I copied directly from the interpreter.

Comment: Oh my bad, I completely missed the `[]`

Comment: Have you tried decoding the strings into ascii and then matching with the regex that works?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand.  The flag doesn't go with the findall when you use it with the compiled object, it only goes to the initial compile function.  That works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second argument to `r.findall` is not flags, but `pos`. You don't need to specify flags again when you already specified them in `compile`.

```
>>> r = re.compile(ur"(\w+)", re.UNICODE)
>>> r.findall(u'test test test')
[u'test', u'test', u'test']
```