# Why does this regex code have different results in Python 2.7 and Python 3.7?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.7

It's to validate username, my codes:

```
import re
regex = r'^[\w.@+-]+\Z'
result = re.match(regex,'名字')
```

In python2.7, it returns `None`.

In python3.7, it returns '名字'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of the different definitions for `\w` in `Python 2.7` versus `Python 3.7`.

In [`Python 2.7`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), we have:

> When the LOCALE and [`UNICODE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50553682/6282576) flags are not specified, matches any
>   alphanumeric character and the underscore; **this is equivalent to the
>   set `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`**.

<sup>(emphasis and hyperlink and formatting added)</sup>

However, in [`Python 3.7`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), we have:

> For Unicode (str) patterns: Matches Unicode word characters; **this
>   includes most characters that can be part of a word in any language,
>   as well as numbers and the underscore**. If the ASCII flag is used, only
>   `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` is matched.

<sup>(emphasis and formatting added)</sup>

So, if you want it to work in both versions, you can do something like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
regex = re.compile(r'^[\w.@+-]+\Z', re.UNICODE)
match = regex.match(u'名字')

if match:
    print(match.group(0))
else:
    print("not matched!")

output:
名字
```

Here's proof that it works in both versions:

[image: works]

Note the differences:

- I added `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of the script, because without it, in `Python 2.7`, we'll get an [error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18078860/6282576) saying

  > Non-ASCII character '\xe5' on line 3, but no encoding declared;  see
  >   http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
- Instead of using `result = re.match(pattern, string)`, I used `regex = re.compile(pattern, flags)` and `match = regex.match(string)` so that I can specify *flags*.
- I used `re.UNICODE` flag, because without it, in `Python 2.7`, it will only match `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` when using `\w`.
- I used `u'名字'` instead of `'名字'`, because in `Python 2.7` you need to use [Unicode Literals](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code) for unicode characters.

Also, while answering your question, I found out that `print("not matched!")` [works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182964/why-is-parenthesis-in-print-voluntary-in-python-2-7) in `Python 2.7` as well, which makes sense, because in this case the parentheses are ignored, which I didn't know, so that was fun.

Comment: Another cross-Py2Py3-compatible print trick: to print just a blank line, replace print with print('').

Comment: @PaulMcG Right on